# django : ImportError No module named myapp.views.hometest

Tags: python, django, mod-wsgi

I have fecora 11, set django with mod_wsgi2.5 and apache2.2. And I can run "python manage.py runserver" at local. It works fine. I got error when i test from remote browser.

Thanks for any suggestion and help!

Answer (score 4):

I just had this problem. It went away when I added `sys.path.append('/path/to/project')` to my .wsgi file.

Answer (score 2):

Is the application containing your Django project in your `$PYTHONPATH` (when Python is invoked in a server context)? For example, if your Django project is at `/home/wwwuser/web/myproj`, then `/home/wwwuser/web` should be in your `$PYTHONPATH`. You should set this in the script that loads the project when invoked from the web server.

Comment: i should put 

PYTHONPATH '['/user/local/django/myproject'+sys.path]' 

in httpd.conf in apache?

Comment: or i should put something in django.wsgi?

Comment: i already had 

sys.path.append('/usr/local/django/myproject')  

in django.wsgi

Comment: how to add Django project path to PYTHONPATH ?

Thanks

Comment: actually i can see in the debug infomation

Python path includes ['/usr/local/django'], myproject's parent directory

Answer (score 1):

Just a guess, but unless you've explicitly made sure that your app is on PYTHONPATH, you should be specifying views in urls.py as myproject.myapp.views.functionname.

Otherwise:

- check if you're setting PYTHONPATH, or what to. Your project directory should be in there.
- if you enable the django admin (by uncommenting the lines that are there by default in urls.py), does that work?

Answer (score 1):

- All required env variables should be set in django.wsgi. You could compare the env declared in django.wsgi and the env of executing `./manage runserver` and make sure they are same.
- Furthermore, if there is another myapp package which could be found through PYTHONPATH before `/usr/local/django/myapp`, `ImportError` may be raised.